# Is it possible to animate a drawable without going through a View?

Tags: android, animation

(I am referring to the old Android animation system here, not the property anims that were introduced with Honeycomb.)

I am trying to wrap my head around how to animate markers on a `MapView`. Since map views use map `Overlay`s, and since overlays are neither views nor expose their markers as `View`s, but as `Drawable`s, I am looking for ways to animate a drawable without putting it in a view container.

Is that possible at all? Looking at the Android sources, it looks as if `Animation` and its various implementations merely contain the code to compute the mathematical transformations an animation applies. Similarly, e.g. `RotateDrawable` only contains the code to compute the rotation, plus code that draws the transformed drawable to a canvas.

However, neither contain code to make an animation play; I was only able to see an animation play when using it through `View.startAnimation(animation)`.

Is there a way to play animations or use an animated drawable without a `View`?

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to wrap my head around how to animate markers on a MapView.

Write your own `Overlay` that works like `ItemizedOverlay` but performs your own animations, either using `ImageView` and the classic animation framework, or your own drawing code.

> Is there a way to play animations or use an animated drawable without a View?

I haven't tried an `AnimationDrawable` with `ItemizedOverlay`, so if a frame-by-frame animation is all you need, that's at least worth a shot. Otherwise, again, you're back to doing your own `Overlay`, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes I already tried something similar to 1): I backed an OverlayItem by an ImageView, and returned its image drawable from OverlayItem.getMarker. However, this only works when I also add the ImageView to the view tree (I added it as a child to MapView), otherwise the animation won't play. If I do that, however, then for some reason the ImageView is rendered /twice/, once with the animation playing, and once without...

Comment: @Matthias: " If I do that, however, then for some reason the ImageView is rendered /twice/, once with the animation playing, and once without..." -- what's probably happening is that the *`Drawable`* is being rendered twice. Certainly that's what I'd expect when you ask `MapView` to display the `Drawable` twice (once as an `OverlayItem`, once as an `ImageView`). Note that I did not say for you to create your own `ItemizedOverlay` -- I said you needed to create your own `Overlay`, bypassing `ItemizedOverlay`, so that you can use `ImageViews` instead of `Drawables`.

Comment: Sure, I could do that. This would mean re-implementing everything that ItemizedOverlay does, like handling focus, interaction, and markers. :-/

Comment: @Matthias: "however, then for some reason the ImageView is rendered /twice/" -- I think setting the imageview to invisible before starting the animation should work for you.

Comment: no, unfortunately it doesn't. Tried that :) Setting it to GONE also doesn't help; this will simply result in the View being removed from layouting entirely, and the animation is gone again. I am currently investigating the effort it takes to do what Mark suggested, i.e. re-implementing a Map overlay that is backed by Views, not Drawables. Will report back when I get anywhere. (The problem is that Overlay and its subclasses are closed source, so I'm pretty much poking in the dark.)

Comment: Yup, it would be really useful if at least the source for `ItemizedOverlay` were available. "This would mean re-implementing everything that ItemizedOverlay does, like handling focus, interaction, and markers" -- yes. BTW, I think @user7777777777 had it backwards. You'd want to hide the `OverlayItem` before doing the animation, since the `ImageView` is what's animating. You could do that either by removing the `OverlayItem` or perhaps by switching it to a transparent marker `Drawable`.

Comment: @Matthias: BTW, osmdroid has an `ItemizedOverlay` implementation you might peek at to get some ideas: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/ItemizedOverlay.java