# Which part of the Android framework is responsible for playing animations?

Tags: android, animation, rendering

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246722/is-it-possible-to-animate-a-drawable-without-going-through-a-view), I am trying to figure out the parts of the Android class library that are responsible for playing an `Animation`. Looking at the sources, the Animation classes seem to merely compute the transformations an animated object undergoes, but they are not responsible for actually "playing" the animation, i.e. rendering the transformed object to the screen at a given frame rate.

I have been sifting through the source code of `View` and `ImageView` for some time now, but I can't make out where the code sits that actually draws each transformation to the screen.

Any ideas?

To clarify, I know that in order to play back an animation, you simply stick it in a `View` and call `startAnimation`, but I'd like to understand which parts of `View` or related classes implement these bits.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the android code. Start at `startAnimation` method of the `View` class.  I think, in view class, after applying the transformation it calls `invalidate()` which leaves the rest to the graphics engine.
The android docs say

> Tweened animation is handled by this package (android.view.animation); frame-by-frame animation is handled by the AnimationDrawable class.

Get the whole summary [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html)

Comment: Yeah I looked at the sources. startAnimation doesn't do anything except for putting the animation into "start mode". There is no drawing logic in there. invalidate() will simply lead to `draw` being called. There is no animation logic in `draw` either as far as I can tell.